# Cannot move into data/data/package (RenameTo fails with ErrnoException EXDEV, Cross-device link)

Tags: android, file-rename, android-file

Is there any chance to move a file inside the device's internal storage

- from /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/video.mp4
- to /data/data//files/video.mp4
- without getting `ErrnoException: rename failed: EXDEV (Cross-device link)` inside `File#renameTo(filename)`

??

I need the rename-operation for performance reasons. Copy and delete takes too much time and requires twice the file size.

Comment: How did the video wind up on external storage in the first place, if that is not where you want it?

Comment: The camera application stores the video there. I get the path from Android's MediaManager. It's not on SD card by the way. My app is for enterprise use only.